# Multiple Column Sorting... not standard sorting though

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, multiple-columns

This is my first post, and I hope someone can help me. I'm not by any stretch a DBA, but I've done quite a bit of work with MSSQL and MySQL. However, I just can't seem to figure this one out. I know how to order by multiple columns, but in this case, the standard "ORDER BY COL1, COL2, COL3" answer doesn't get me the data in the order in which I would like it to appear in the web app I'm building. This is in MSSQL Express 2008 R2.

The query I have is not terribly complex, as it contains a few simple joins to get some extra data. It does run between a couple of databases in the same instance. The basics of the query follow:

```
select rt.TotalsID, rl.LookupName, rt.RegisterNum, cin.userFirstName, rt.CashInDate 
from [RegisterApp].[dbo].[Reg_Totals] rt 
inner join [RegisterApp].[dbo].[Reg_Lookup] rl on rl.LookupID = rt.StoreID 
inner join [KR_Users_Groups_Permissions].[dbo].[tbl_user] cin on cin.userId = rt.CashInUserID 
inner join [KR_Users_Groups_Permissions].[dbo].[tbl_user] cout on cout.userId = rt.CashOutUserID
```

I would like to order the results by rt.CashInDate, then rl.LookupName, then rt.RegisterNum. However, as I said, just the standard multi-column order by statement doesn't fulfill my needs. As the data in question can be input in any order, the results when ordered that way will indeed order by the most recent date first (rt.CashInDate desc), but then the rl.LookupName and rt.RegisterNum values are subject to the time in the first column. What I would like to see in the results is that for each day, the rl.LookupName is then sorted ascending, and then for each rl.LookupName within that, each rt.RegisterNum result is then sorted ascending as well.

With a standard

```
order by rt.CashInDate desc, rl.LookupName, rt.RegisterNum
```

the results vary depending on what the rt.CashInDate is per row. For example, the results from yesterday appear like this with the above order by statement:

```
TotalsID  LookupName      RegisterNum     userFirstName   CashInDate
      12  Polyclinic      RG2             Joshua          2012-11-28 10:18:00
      13  Polyclinic      RG3             Joshua          2012-11-28 10:18:00
      11  Polyclinic      RG1             Joshua          2012-11-28 09:56:00
      10  Downtown        RG1             JJ              2012-11-28 08:22:00
```

What I would like to see is the data displayed like this:

```
TotalsID LookupName  RegisterNum userFirstName  CashInDate
10       Downtown    RG1         JJ             2012-11-28 08:22:00
11       Polyclinic  RG1         Joshua         2012-11-28 09:56:00
12       Polyclinic  RG2         Joshua         2012-11-28 10:18:00
13       Polyclinic  RG3         Joshua         2012-11-28 10:18:00
```

Granted, for the results from yesterday, the rt.TotalsID is in order, but that isn't always the case either. For example, here are the results from the 26th as they would appear in the order I'd like to see them in:

```
TotalsID  LookupName  RegisterNum userFirstName  CashInDate
5         Downtown    RG1         JJ             2012-11-26 08:27:00
2         Polyclinic  RG1         Joshua         2012-11-26 07:33:00
3         Polyclinic  RG2         Joshua         2012-11-26 07:33:00
4         Polyclinic  RG3         Joshua         2012-11-26 07:33:00
```

Notice the rt.TotalsID is not in order in this case.

I've been hitting Google pretty hard, with not much luck. Perhaps I'm just not phrasing my searches correctly. I hope this request is comprehensible, and that someone can help. In the end, it's not absolutely necessary that I get the data back in this order, but it's what I'd really like to see.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice!

Malachi

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention the third join is in use, I just didn't include every column I'm pulling data from in the example query I provided.

Comment: You might sort by date part of CashInDate only: `order by cast (rt.CashInDate as date) desc, rl.LookupName, rt.RegisterNum`.

Comment: @Nikola you have to make that an answer.

Comment: Wow... this is why I came here. That's absolutely what I should do Nikola, thank you! I really don't know why I didn't think of that. I guess I was trying to over-complicate this, as I've been known to do. That's a beautiful, simple solution. If you make that an answer, as jachguate suggests, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

From @Nikola's comment:

You need to sort by the date part of `CashInDate` only:

`ORDER BY CAST(rt.CashInDate AS DATE) desc, rl.LookupName, rt.RegisterNum`